# Unknown applet keep asking for authorisation, how to stop it?

Tags: security, java-applet

I am getting this error every 15 minutes. How can I stop it? I can't find where it's been installed. Here is an image of what I am getting:

[image]

The Name is MyApplet, the publisher is Unknown, the from is http://webkarskim.nilayatesogullari.com

Here is the result of the scan:

```
Scan type: Quick scan
Scan options enabled: Memory | Startup | Registry | File System | Heuristics/Extra | Heuristics/Shuriken | PUP | PUM
Scan options disabled: P2P
Objects scanned: 261400
Time elapsed: 11 minute(s), 30 second(s)

Memory Processes Detected: 1
C:\Windows\csrss.exe (Backdoor.Bot) -> 520 -> Delete on reboot.

Memory Modules Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Registry Keys Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Registry Values Detected: 1
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run|ClientServerRuntime (Backdoor.Bot) -> Data: C:\Windows\csrss.exe -> Quarantined and deleted successfully.

Registry Data Items Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Folders Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Files Detected: 1
C:\Windows\csrss.exe (Backdoor.Bot) -> Delete on reboot.
```

Comment: If you now Google for "csrss.exe Backdoor.Bot" you find plenty of info, including suggestions to use MalwareBytes as vjones suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like some Malware trying to install itself on your computer.  It doesn't look like it has actually been installed yet - the screen shot you posted shows it trying to run from a particular url.

Have you completely closed any browsers you have running?  If so (and you still have that message)  the next step is probably to run something like [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free/) (you can use the free version) to see if you've got some kind of malware infection - there could be another piece of malware that *did* get installed that is trying to install this second program.